# AsyncTask in copy Database from asset folder in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-database

I want use `AsyncTask` for copy **database** in my application. The application has 4 fragments, and any fragment shows one table from the database (database has 4 tables). But when I run the application, show me this **error:**

**Attention :** I am an amateur. Please guide me instead of give me negative point!

```
03-07 12:49:18.775 11190-11190/com.tellfa.dastanak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tellfa.dastanak, PID: 11190
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbl_Book (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:897)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:508)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
at com.tellfa.dastanak.Database.DataBase.getCat1_Datas(DataBase.java:157)
at com.tellfa.dastanak.Fragments.Home_Frag.onCreateView(Home_Frag.java:49)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
at android.view.Vi
```

**AsyncTask code :**

```
public class LoadDB_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    Context mContext;
    boolean loadedDB = false;
    private DataBase dataBase;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "log : ";

    public LoadDB_AsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPreExecute in loadDB");
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Data loading ...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onProgressUpdate in loadDB");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "doInBackground in loadDB");

        dataBase = new DataBase(mContext);
        boolean dbExist = dataBase.checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            loadedDB = true;
        } else {
            publishProgress(null);
        }

        try {
            dataBase.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error on create DataBase");
        }

        dataBase.close();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPostExecute in loadDB");

        if (!loadedDB) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Loaded DataBase");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The database was already loaded");
        }
        try {
            finalize();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**DataBase code:**

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME = "Dastansara";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }

        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database alerdy exist
        } else {

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            /// database does't exist yet
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Open DataBase
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        String myPATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    /**
     * Close DataBase
     */
    public void closeDataBase() {

        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(myPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public Cursor getCat1_Datas(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"1"});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment code:**

```
public class Home_Frag extends Fragment {

    DataProvider dataProvider;
    DataBase dataBase;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView listView;
    Cat1_frag_adapter cat1FragAdapter;
    private LoadDB_AsyncTask task;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home,
                container, false);

        task = new LoadDB_AsyncTask(getContext());
        task.execute();

        dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
        sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dataBase.getCat1_Datas(sqLiteDatabase);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        cat1FragAdapter = new Cat1_frag_adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_card_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(cat1FragAdapter);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        }

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String id;
                String title;
                //id = cursor.getString(0);
                title = cursor.getString(2);

                dataProvider = new DataProvider(title);
                cat1FragAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

How to fix this error and use `Asynctask` in my application? tnx <3

Comment: I think, your main issues is that you are trying to copy database in Async task which runs in its own thread and before your DB gets copied into your device you are trying to access the DB that why it is giving you error of no such table exists. First complete your DB copy and then try to access data from the DB.

Comment: You're querying for a table that doesn't exist.  That means either the copy isn't finished yet (you need to wait for the copy to be done before using it),  or the table really doesn't exist which means either your db file is bad or your query is.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki, thanks you. can you send me sample code? i really need this for project

Comment: @GabeSechan, thanks you. can you send me sample code? i really need this for project

Comment: I am sorry i dont have code for your question, but from your code i can guide you.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki, if you send me code with my codes, it's very good. just help me pleaseeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task = new LoadDB_AsyncTask(getContext());
    task.execute();
```

You will do above task first and on completion of the above task you will do following task.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPostExecute in loadDB");

        if (!loadedDB) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Loaded DataBase");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The database was already loaded");
        }
        try {
            finalize();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
            sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = dataBase.getCat1_Datas(sqLiteDatabase);
            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            cat1FragAdapter = new Cat1_frag_adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_card_layout);
            listView.setAdapter(cat1FragAdapter);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            }
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String id;
                    String title;
                    //id = cursor.getString(0);
                    title = cursor.getString(2);

                    dataProvider = new DataProvider(title);
                    cat1FragAdapter.add(dataProvider);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My dear friend, i write this code above post!!! please see **Fragment code:** codes in above post! i write you codes

Comment: I know you have written above code, but you have not read what i write in the answer, i said, On Completion of Asynch task you need to call database related code. That means from your async task OnPostExecute you need to notify your fragment that you db copy has been finished and you can now access the DB using your next piece of code. I hope you are getting what i am explaining you.

Comment: oh oh yeees sorry i'm not read your descriptions, sorry man <3 . can you send me code for second part of your description ? my mean this : `That means from your async task OnPostExecute you need to notify your fragment that you db copy has been finished and you can now access the DB using your next piece of code. I hope you are getting what i am explaining you.`  i am an amateur and need your help

Comment: I have updated piece of code for you, if it worked for you then please accept this answer, or at least upvote this answer.

Comment: WoooooooooooooW!!!! it's oooooooook maaaan. yeees. you are very great maaaan. thanks my dear friend. special thanks my friend <3